# ZeroMQ subscribing in Delphi

Tags: python, delphi, tcp, zeromq

I'm currently using ZeroMQ to send serialized data objects from a Python server to a Delphi client. As you probably know there are different kinds of models for a ZeroMQ connection, I'm using both request/reply and publish/subscribe.

The request/reply model works great, no problems at all. But when I'm trying to subscribe for data in the Delphi client, data which come from the ZeroMQ publisher written in Python, I'm having trouble getting the data. The code I use for subscribing to the data looks like this:

```
PubZeroMQ.zErr( ctx=nil );
skt_pub := zmq_socket(ctx, ZMQ_SUB);
PubZeroMQ.zErr( ctx=nil );
zmq_setsockopt( skt_pub, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, 0, 0);
PubZeroMQ.zErr( 0<>zmq_connect(skt_pub, 'tcp://*:6001'));
```

And then I try to read data using this code:

```
lvbytes := PubZeroMQ.zSubscribe(skt_pub);
```

zSubscribe looks like this:

```
zmq_msg_init(@m);
r := zmq_recv(zSocket, @m, 0);
zErr( (r<>0) and (zmq_errno()<>11) ); // 11 = Resource temporarily unavailable
r := zmq_msg_size(@m);
SetLength(Result, r);
System.Move( zmq_msg_data(@m)^, Result[1], r );
```

I tried debugging and my program gets stuck at `zmq_recv(zSocket, @m, 0);` as if it's waiting for some data but doesn't get it. The zmq_recv function looks like this

```
function  zmq_recv(s : Pointer; msg : Pzmq_msg_t; flags : Integer) : Integer; cdecl;
```

The connection seems to be fine as I don't have any problems using the request/reply model and also I'm sure the python server is publishing data as I have another client in C++ which works great. Am I doing the subscription wrong?

Here is how I'm doing the subscribing in the c++ client

```
void* subscriber = zmq_socket( context, ZMQ_SUB );
zmq_setsockopt( subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0 );
zmq_connect( subscriber, "tcp://*:6001" );
```

And the read:

```
const unsigned int BUFF_SIZE = 1024;
char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
size_t size;

size = zmq_recv( subscriber, (void*)&buffer[0], BUFF_SIZE, 0 );
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which Delphi client are you using? (It might be easier to answer the question if the code is available)

Comment: I solved it by downloading [this](https://github.com/zedalaye/Delphi-ZeroMQ) package and using the examples. Don't know what the error was. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [this package](https://github.com/zedalaye/Delphi-ZeroMQ), the error will go away.

(a better answer is not easy/possible without seeing the original client source code)